# Can't open an image in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resources, xamlparseexception

In my application I want to display some pictures (I need to have them stored in a list). I have problem with opening them. Firstly, I made a directory Images (using VS). Next I loaded pictures to this folder (also in VS).
I wanted to open one of them like here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970062.aspx

```
Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream("Images\bulbOff.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
PngBitmapDecoder decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
```

And then while trying to run the program, I got:

```
XamlParseException
```

with hardly any information.
For sure the first line is causing the problem, because the problem disappears only when I delete it.

I tried to do it also like:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("Images\bulbOff.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
PngBitmapDecoder decoder2 = new PngBitmapDecoder(myUri, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapSource bitmapSource2 = decoder2.Frames[0];
```

with the same result.
I also tried to copy the image to main folder of app (in SolutionView). When I tried to get "\bulbOff.png" the result was the same.
When I tried to get "bulbOff.png" I got

```
XamlParseException
```

again, but with some info - there were hints that path could be wrong.

Comment: Why does loading an image throws a XamlParseException ? Are you 100% sure that the exception is related to loading the image?

Comment: Move that code so that it doesn't happen right when the control is instantiated. Any exception thrown during construction, indirectly called from XAML, will be caught and an XamlParseException thrown. However, InnerException (or perhaps several levels of InnerException) should reveal the real error.

Comment: @Gerardo  As I wrote I tried deleting the code line by line starting from the last one. And the exception have been stopped being thrown after deleting the first line (in both examples it contains the path to the file).

Comment: please post your full exception here

Comment: Ok I see... check and post the inner exceptions to see whats happening below the XamlParseException (wich is a wrapper ex, it tells us nothing at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx)...

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri(@"..\Images\DocumentAccess_16x16.png", UriKind.Relative);
image.EndInit();
```

...where Images is a folder within your project.

Comment: 1. As far as I know BitmapImage is just mplementation of abstract class ImageSource.
2. In both examples you are using only BitmapImage, so what do you mean by provide an ImageSource?

Comment: @rideronthestorm You are correct about ImageSource being the higher level type, edited accordingly, give the BitmapImage route a go I know for a fact that it works...it is sitting in code right now

Comment: Doesn't a png image have to be decoded?   What does the '@' stand for and why in the begining of the path you typed '../'(go to upper level in files tree)?

Comment: @rideronthestorm No it does not need manually decoded; @ forces a string literal on the URI, so no escaping is needed...yes it is going up one level...

Comment: OK, it worked in the way that you've showed. But the question is why it didn't worked in the way that was posted at the Microsoft www (MSDN)? I tried also to use the path with '@' and '../" with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your image and code to a jpg extension. Seriously.